# AWS SES and Rails. My app doesn't send the mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon AWS SES to send the common confirmation emails when a user get registered. I have my email and domain verified, but Rails doesn't send the message.

I have installed aws-ses gem and it works because i've done some trys from Rails console. But when it has to send it automatically, i get:

```
I, [2013-11-13T12:36:21.953813 #3262]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1623ms
F, [2013-11-13T12:36:21.958860 #3262] FATAL -- : 
AWS::SES::ResponseError (MessageRejected - Email address is not verified.):
```

My amazon_ses.rb looks like:

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
  access_key_id: 'ACCESS_KEY_ID',
  secret_access_key: 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
```

And my production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'ismuser.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
```

I'm just guessing the problem is i have not defined the source email (the email verified in SES), but i don't know where i should define it.

Help?

Comment: You might want to remove your access + secret key?!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same issue today.

After some debugging I figured SES was instanciating using the wrong server (I'im using EU whereas US is default).

```
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
  server: "email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
  access_key_id: PLEASE_REMOVE_YOUR_CREDENTIALS_FROM_QUESTION,
  secret_access_key: PLEASE_REMOVE_YOUR_CREDENTIALS_FROM_QUESTION
```

did the trick for me.

Hope this can help someone someday ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
AWS::SES::ResponseError (MessageRejected - Email address is not verified.)
```

This means that you have to verify the email address for using it with SES. The easiest way to do this is log into the Web Console, go to SES and click on Email Addresses and then Verify a new address.

Also, you should make sure that you're sending the message from the same email address you have verified.

Comment: I have already verified my email. Even the domain. What i need is a way to tell to aws-ses the source email from i want to send the message.

Comment: If it helps, I use this code to actually send the message: ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => from, :to => params[:to], :subject => params[:subject], :body => params[:contents], :content_type => "text/html").deliver

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what went wrong. Another way is to use smtp delivery method.

In AWS panel, Click the button for “Create My SMTP credentials”

Record the user name and password created

Add this to your development and production.rb files:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  :user_name => "..." # Your SMTP user here.
  :password => "...", # Your SMTP password here.
  :authentication => :login,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's some tips from Amazon themselves:

> Congratulations!
>
> You have successfully verified an email address with Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES). You can now begin sending email from this address.
>
> *If you are a new Amazon SES user and have not yet received [production access](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/fullaccessrequest/) to Amazon SES, then you can only send email **to** addresses **that you have previously verified**.* To view your list of verified email addresses, go to the [Amazon SES console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses) or refer to the [Amazon SES Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html).
>
> If you have already been approved for production access, then you can send email to any address.

— [Verification Successful @ Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) | AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/verifysuccess/)

> **Your Amazon SES account has "sandbox" access in region EU (Ireland).**
>   With sandbox access you can only send email to the Amazon SES mailbox
>   simulator and to email addresses or domains that you have verified. To
>   be moved out of the sandbox, please request a sending limit increase.
>   [Learn more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/ses/sandbox).

— [Sending Statistics @ SES Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses#dashboard:)

So apparently email verification alone is not enough, you'll have to request *production access* to be able to send emails to the real world.

After submitting *production access* request, you'll get a message like:

> Hello,
>
> Congratulations! After reviewing your case, we have increased your
>   sending quota to 50,000 messages per day and your maximum send rate to
>   14 messages per second in AWS Region EU (Ireland). Your account has
>   also been moved out of the sandbox, so you no longer need to verify
>   recipient addresses.

Make sure that you picked `Yes` for **all** bureaucratic `Yes/No` questions, otherwise a Support Engineer may reject your request. Apparently this works like Disclaimer/License Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused when your region isn't registered as the same with your app and SES. Look in the top right hand corner of your AWS SES dashboard/console and you will see the region name. Then use this code to compare the too:

```
ses = AWS::SES::Base.new(access_key_id: ENV['AWS_KEY'],secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET'])
```

To create a new connection in the Rails Console. It will spit out output like so:

```
=> #<AWS::SES::Base:0x00000110d37618
 @access_key_id="<access_key_value>",
 @http=#<Net::HTTP email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443 open=false>,
 @path="/",
 @port=443,
 @proxy_server=nil,
 @secret_access_key="<secret_key_value>",
 @server="email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
 @settings={},
 @use_ssl=true,
 @user_agent="github-aws-ses-ruby-gem">
```

If your regions don't match set it specifically with:

```
ses = AWS::SES::Base.new(
   access_key_id: ENV['AWS_KEY'],
   secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET'], 
   server: 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
   )
```